# Stuck in making a react project

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

guys. I'm having a trouble when using `npx create-react-app` script.
Whenever I try to create a react app, it's always show like this:

```
Creating a new React app in C:\USER\User\Document\GitHub\Projects

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...
```

And it always stuck in there. I ever leave it for almost eight hours, but still it ain't work.

I've been trying to do `npm install npm@latest -g` to install the latest version of my npm, but still it doesn't work. I even have tried to uninstall the NodeJS in my computer, then reinstall it.

Earlier, I've always done my react projects with this method:

```
npm init
npm install create-react-app
npm create-react-app my-project
```

Unfortunately, after a week, I cannot do `npm start` for every react project that I've made before using that method. I also have tried to use the same method to create a new react project, but still it always stuck in the same part. I really need your help guys.

I'm using the latest version of VSCode on Windows 8.1 by the way.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What Node version are you on? `node -v`

Comment: It's 15.5.1 current version

Comment: Have you tried starting a project in a different directory? Remove the global `create-react-app` and the use `npx create-react-app` but in a different directory.

Comment: Yes, then some errors coming up.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-11T15_46_39_732Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you might be hosting an old version of `create-react-app`
Here are some processes for you to try out:

1. Uninstall the global version of create-react-app.
   `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
2. Run the following command to delete the create-react-app manually.
   `rm -rf /usr/local/bin/create-react-app`
3. Now, you can use the `npx create-react-app` command to create a new app.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for my PC. Still stuck at the same part. Do you have another idea, sir?